# Calendly not syncing with Google calendar--"quota exceeded" error

Tags: google-calendar-api, quota, calendly

I'm not a developer and I'm way out of my depths here but I'm hoping I can find some help here. I've been using Calendly to sync to my Google calendar. It no longer syncs and gives this error:

> 125 TID-ec5p Calendar::PushJob JID-61bdee4b8fb5024dcab6c443 ERROR: [CalendarHub::Runner::SingleService] context={:user_id=>6154125, :calendar_kind=>"google", :calendar_account_id=>6860855, :calendar_name=>"Google Calendar", :action_name=>:create_event} exception=#"info@leecrockett.com", :calendar_kind=>"google", :calendar_account_id=>6860855, :calendar_version=>nil, :calendar_name=>"Google Calendar", :action_name=>:create_event, :response_status=>403, :response_body=>"{  "error": {   "errors": [    {     "domain": "usageLimits",     "reason": "quotaExceeded",     "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."    }   ],   "code": 403,   "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."  } } "}

Calendly directed me to Google and Google support says they don't do anything with APIs and directed me here. Is there a way to fix this? I'm missing appointments because they are no longer syncing and need to get this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's not a lot you (or Calendly) can do here except creating fewer events and/or inviting fewer people.

Google has a page listing their error codes, which defines this one as abuse protection.

From [Handle API Errors](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_calendar_usage_limits_exceeded):

> The user reached one of the Google Calendar limits in place to protect Google users and infrastructure from abusive behavior.

See [Avoid Calendar use limits](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#403_calendar_usage_limits_exceeded) for more details on what the actual limits are.

Answer (score 0):

> Calendar usage limits exceeded.

Ever application created to use Googles apis has a limit placed on it as to how many requests it can make over a period of time.  This is called quota.   Your application has reached the limit of the number of requests it can make. You need to wait until tomorrow and try again this time make fewer requests.